# AWS Glue with S3 endpoint and bucket policy

Tags: aws-glue

I have a current S3 and Glue infra as below.

S3 endpoint deployed in VPC
S3 buckets having bucket policy to allow traffic only from endpoint.
GLUE IAM Role which has access to the said bucket.

When i run a AWS Glue Crawler job I am getting an error "User does not have access to S3 bucket"
I tried providing IAM User ID access to S3 bucket. I added IAM role and IAM ID in S3 bucket policy. But the error continues.

When i remove the bucket policy and even with IAM user ID having no access to the bucket the crawler job is success.

Per AWS documentation AWS Glue uses S3 endpoint. If it does then why am i getting this error?

Comment: Sorry, but your explanation is a little difficult to follow. Could you possibly expand your question with examples of the policies and configurations you are using, so we can attempt to reproduce your situation?

Answer (score 0):

I recently hit this as well when I was configuring a Glue Crawler's Role to access a previously created S3 bucket created by the same user. The issue I had was that while I did set the resource permission for the contents of the bucket `arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>/*` I wasn't setting permissions for the bucket itself `arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>`.

I'm using the AWS CDK for my example but I think it's easy enough to see what I mean in the code below:

```
new iam.PolicyStatement({
  effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
  resources: [
    `arn:aws:s3:::${bucketName}`,
    `arn:aws:s3:::${bucketName}/*`,
  ],
  actions: ["s3:*"],
}),
```